# Playwright C# - Handling Common Components and Their Actions

Tags: c#, ui-automation, playwright, playwright-dotnet

### **Overview**

I am looking at transitioning away from an extensive C# Selenium project into PlayWright as a POC.

As part of this our application uses an internal component library which we automate through using selenium and a number of component classes which our testers just need to reference in their Page file along with the unique locator, which then exposes a number of actions available to them which can be performed on that component (some are simple, some have complex/multiple steps) which are all accessed via a method off the component(class).

For example:

**Page**

```
public readonly Input depositValue = Input.ByName("depositValue");
```

**Steps**

```
page.depositPercentage.EnterValue(10.00);
```

### **Question**

In Playwright I would like to do something similar to this, making a centralised location for each component which can be maintained in one location.

The issues I have here are:

- Some of our applications are contained in a master IFrame (IFrameLocator) where as others exist without an Iframe so can use IPage. Is there a way to make a generic Interface which would work for both of these examples?
- the syntax for Playwright is very different to that we use for Selenium, I would like to make it so our components work in a similar flow to playwright's default language. Is this possible?

e.g. for Component X this would look like:

MyPage

```
ILocator fieldx = page.page.ComponentXLocator("unique locator"); <- Note this is usually a Data-TestId
```

Steps

```
await myPage.fieldx.SelectFromListAsync()
```

In an ideal world I would also like to surface all the built in ILocator interface actions here so users can still benefit from the Assertion Library and built in actions and not just the custom ones.

Any help with this would be fantastic. Playwright seems to have a lot of potential, but maintainability is key for us to reduce overhead when our component library (handled by another team internally) change their UI

Many thanks

Comment: Check the [Page Object Models](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/pom) page. Instead of exposing locators to other code, store them in fields and expose only high-level calls. This way the code is less fragile and callers don't need to know the low-level design of the page. If you pass `IPage` in the constructor, you can create the locators in the constructor. You can do the same for UI components, by creating new locators over an existing parent locator